# Proof that state at time $n+1$ depends only on the state at time $n$ using definition of Markov property

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I'm learning about the Markov process in class and I have this step that is quite trivial that I don't know how to show. I also don't know how to go about googling this.

I want to show that:
$$P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1}  |X_n = i_n, X _{n-1} = i_{n-1}) = P(X_{n+1}  = i_{n+1} |X_n  = i _n).$$
The definition I’m given is
$$P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} |X_n = i_n, \ldots , X_0  = i_0) = P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1}  |X_n = i_n).$$
How do I use the definition to derive the first equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write $$
P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\mid X_n=i_n, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1})=
\frac{P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}, X_n=i_n, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}) }
{P(X_n=i_n, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}) }\tag1
$$
The key is to consider all the values of the variables $X_{n-2}, X_{n-3},\ldots, X_2, X_1, X_0$ not mentioned. Use $\bf Y$ as shorthand for this vector of unmentioned variables. Then the numerator of the RHS of (1) can be written
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{\bf y}&P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}, X_n=i_n, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},{\bf Y}={\bf y})\\
&\stackrel{(1)}=\sum_{\bf y}P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\mid X_n=i_n, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},{\bf Y}={\bf y})P(X_n=i_n, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},{\bf Y}={\bf y})\\
&\stackrel{(2)}=\sum_{\bf y}P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\mid X_n=i_n)P(X_n=i_n, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},{\bf Y}={\bf y})\\
&\stackrel{(3)}=P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\mid X_n=i_n)\sum_{\bf y}P(X_n=i_n, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},{\bf Y}={\bf y})\\
&=P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\mid X_n=i_n)P(X_n=i_n, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1})\\
\end{align}
$$
where the sum is taken over all possible values $\bf y$ of $\bf Y$. Step (1) is the definition of conditional probability; step (2) is the Markov property; step (3) pulls out a factor that doesn't depend on $\bf y$.

Answer (score 1):

I had a different answer before that was possibly incorrect, so I use another proof technique here.

---

The result will be shown by induction. I first show the result is true for $n = 1$, and then show it is true for $n$ assuming it is true for $n -1$.

For $n = 1$, by definition
$$P(X_2 = i_2 \mid X_1 = i_1, X_0 = i_0) = P(X_2 = i_2 \mid X_1 = i_1
)$$

Assume result is true for $X_n$, that is, assume

$$P(X_{n} = i_n \mid X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, X_{n-2} = i_{n-2}) = P(X_{n} = i_n \mid X_{n-1} = i_{n-1})  $$

Using the above, we will prove the result for $X_{n+1}$.

This is straightforward from the definition of conditional distribution, but I spell the steps out here for you.
\begin{align*}
&P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} \mid X_n = i_n, X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}) \\
 = &\sum_{i_{n-2},\dots, i_0}P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1}, X_n = i_n, X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, X_{n-2} = i_{n-2},  \dots, X_{i_0} = i_0 \mid X_n = i_n, X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}) \\
 = &\sum_{i_{n-2},\dots, i_0}\dfrac{P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1}, X_n = i_n, X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, X_{n-2} = i_{n-2},  \dots, X_{i_0} = i_0) }{P(X_n = i_n, X_{n-1} = i_{n-1})}\\
 = &\sum_{i_{n-2},\dots, i_0}\dfrac{P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1}, X_n = i_n, X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, X_{n-2} = i_{n-2},  \dots, X_{i_0} = i_0) }{P(X_n = i_n \mid X_{n-1} = i_{n-1})\,\, P(X_{n-1} = i_{n-1})}\\
 = &\sum_{i_{n-2},\dots, i_0}\dfrac{P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1}, X_n = i_n, X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, X_{n-2} = i_{n-2},  \dots, X_{i_0} = i_0) }{P(X_n = i_n \mid X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, X_{n-2} = i_{n-2} , \dots, X_0 = i_0)\,\, P(X_{n-1} = i_{n-1})}\\
 = &\sum_{i_{n-2},\dots, i_0}\dfrac{P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1}, X_n = i_n, X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, X_{n-2} = i_{n-2},  \dots, X_{i_0} = i_0) }{P(X_n = i_n,X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, X_{n-2} = i_{n-2} , \dots, X_0 = i_0)\,\,}\\
& \quad \quad \quad \times \dfrac{P(X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, X_{n-2} = i_{n-2} , \dots, X_0 = i_0)}{ P(X_{n-1} = i_{n-1})} \\
 = &\sum_{i_{n-2},\dots, i_0}P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} \mid X_n = i_n, X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, X_{n-2} = i_{n-2},  \dots, X_{i_0} = i_0) \\
& \quad \quad \quad \times P(X_{n-2} = i_{n-2} , \dots, X_0 = i_0 \mid X_{n-1} = i_{n-1},) \\
 = &\sum_{i_{n-2},\dots, i_0}P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} \mid X_n = i_n) \,\, P(X_{n-2} = i_{n-2} , \dots, X_0 = i_0 \mid X_{n-1} = i_{n-1},) \\
 = &P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} \mid X_n = i_n) \,\,\sum_{i_{n-2},\dots, i_0} P(X_{n-2} = i_{n-2} , \dots, X_0 = i_0 \mid X_{n-1} = i_{n-1},) \\
 = &P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} \mid X_n = i_n) \,.
\end{align*}

Thus proved by induction.

(I believe there has to be an easier proof for this, but this is all I have at this point.)

Comment: In the first step why do you get $P(X_n=i_n)P(X_{n−1}=i_{n−1})$ in the denominator? Shouldn't it be $P(X_n = i_n, X_{n-1} = i_{n-1})$?

Comment: @liyuan Well spotted. I have changed my answer.

Comment: There is, it's simpler than I thought!